# jquery fadeOut div in td with timer

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout, html-table

I try to fadeOut a div. It works with hide(), but not with fadeOut()

```
mobileLabnavhideTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
                          $('#labStageNavContainer').hide();
                         }, 
                         4000);
```

The div is in a table td. Is this a problem?

Comment: $('#labStageNavContainer').fadeOut(); should work

Comment: Instead of showing the code that works, it is more helpful if you show the actual code that *doesn't* work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working with [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8MuRn/) to see if that's what you are looking for.

**Code from Demo:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.setTimeout(function(){
                          $('#labStageNavContainer').fadeOut();
                         },
                         4000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#div').fadeout('slow', function(){
             //do whatever here afer fades out
             //can change 'slow' to time in milliseconds 5000 would be 5 seconds
});

I think that's what your trying to do their is also .delay()